# Правильное окончание и пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, окончания

*«Кто отвернулся первым:

Бог от человека

Или от Бога человек?*»

Вопроса два:
1) Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?
2) Какое окончание лучше выбрать в слове "первым"? Может, "первый"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) Кто отвернулся первым: (2) Бог (отвернулся) от человека или (3) человек (отвернулся) от Бога ?**

1) Сложное предложение состоит из трех простых предложений. **Запятая перед одиночным союзом ИЛИ не ставится,** так как предложения (2) и (3) раскрывают содержание предложения (1), то есть бессоюзная связь с предложением (1) является **общим элементом**.

2) **Форма Т.п.** (отвернулся первым) в современном языке более предпочтительна, также Т.п. обычно обозначает временной признак, в то время как И.п. чаще относится к постоянному признаку.